# set hidden field value in parent page from iframe page

Tags: iframe, same-origin-policy

Page A has an iframe that loads Page B in it.

```
<div style="display:block; height:0px; width:0px;">
<iframe id="frame1" height="0" width="0"></iframe>
</div>
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" id="IsFileGenerated" Value="False"/>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function () {
frame1.src = [Page B];}
```

On page B a file is downloaded (on pageLoad) after which i want to set the hiddenField value on Page A..Is it possible?

page A has a button on whose click i need to check if the file is downloaded..

Answer (score 0):

OK, as soon as I post a question, it hits me !

Here is what I did

**Page A**

```
<div style="display:none"><label id="IsFileGenerated">False</label></div>
```

JS - On button click

```
if ($('#IsFileGenerated').text() == "True") {//do something}
```

**Page B**

```
function OnFileDownloaded(data) {
        parent.document.getElementById("IsFileGenerated").innerHTML = "True";
    }
```